# How to test client- server architecture when using UDP?

Tags: java, udp

I'm creating a small multiplayer game project using Java and I wanted to know if it were possible to test the client- server architecture on one machine. At the moment there is 1 client and 1 server, the client can send messages to the server as the server listens, then when the server responds to the client, instead of the clients listener reading the packet it gets looped back to the server.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You probably have a bug in your code, or you have somehow managed to set up your client and server so they both use the same port number.

Comment: I thought that's the general practice? should I have an inbound port and an outbound port instead?

Comment: General practice is for the server to listen on a fixed know port number, and for the client to chose a port at random(let the operating system choose an available port). If you use the same port number on your client and server, you'll not be able to easily test both the client and server running on the same machine, nor could you run many clients on one machine. It would probably be better to show the client and server code that creates the socket and sends/receives messages so people can give you better advice.

Comment: I put the client and the server on different ports and now I can get 1 server and 1 client to connect to each other fine so that's good! 1 thing I'm worried about however is the fact the client would have to portforward to use this over the internet wouldn't they? and I don't want that.

Comment: No, they wouldn't need any port forwarding, as long as the client initiates the connection(sends the 1. UDP packet). If your server is behind a NAT gateway, you'll need set up port forwarding for that though.

Comment: Oh okay great, post the first thing you said as an answer <3

Comment: @nos I've tried using your method and as I suspected the client on the other end is unable to send information to me, they can receive information but not send it how can I allow information to be sent two ways?

Comment: @ShainWild I've no idea what you did, or how the network setup you have looks like, so that's pretty hard to answer.

Comment: If I give you a link to my bitbucket can you take a look at my server- client code? ;)